# What is the difference between Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and finish in android

Tags: android

What is the difference between `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `finish()` in Android?

Comment: do you see any similarity in these two . first one is an intent flag while second is an Activity delegate .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The differerence between these two are as follows:

1.**finish()** you can use to end the activity in which you are right now present and also it will end one activity at one time.

2.In case of **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**,It will end all the activities those are on top of the current activities inside the stack.There may be more than one activity.

Comment: Judging by your explanation I think you should remove the sentence "Both do the same work". It implies the opposite of the rest of your answer. The rest is very informative, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

suppose you are starting activities one after another in the order
 A-->B-->C-->D,ie activity B started from activity A,activity C started from activity B and so on.
Now calling startactivity(A) from activity D with intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP finishes all activities in between (here B and C) and starts A.

calling Finish() from your activity closes current activity

Answer (score 1):

`finish()` android uses to end the activity by calling it in program.
(Note, you can also use `onDestroy()`).
`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` clears all the activities that are top of the current activities inside the Activity stack.